# Input string format is not correct in ftp web request

Tags: c#, string, formatexception

I am creating a file on ftp server. But Before creating file on server I also check that it does not existing already. However, It is working fine most of the system but one of my client has problem. When he run the application, it throws the system.formatexception i-e input string is not in correct format.

I am unable to understand this problem. Can anybody help me?

The following is the code to create file.

```
 public string createFile(string filename1)
           {

            StreamWriter sw1 = null;
            System.Net.FtpWebRequest tmpReq1;
            try
            {
            tmpReq1 = (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.dunyameri.com/pt/" + filename1);
            tmpReq1.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("naveed@dunyameri.com", "xxxxx");
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)tmpReq1.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                FtpWebResponse response2 = (FtpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                if (response2.StatusCode == FtpStatusCode.ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable)
                    {
                        // I am creating file here
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return ex.ToString();
                    }
            }
            return "File Created";

        }
```

I haves searched on internet that it might be because of string contain 0 or dots. In this particular system case the file name contain dots and 0. Is it because of this type of file name?

[image: Exception description]

Thanks,
Naveed

Comment: The lines in try section through this exception, even though i am catching web exception but still i got system.formatexception.

Comment: @NaveedQamar what is the value inside filename1

Comment: cntsnwv0cn145.xx.xx.xxx.net-file.csv this is the value in this particular case ... I tried use ip 192.001.012.211-file.csv but it does not work. But when i use these file names on my system it does work fine.

Comment: Can you show your file creation code?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the error does not occur within "createFile(string filename1)". If so, the stack should be similar to this:

```
...
System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
e2erta.e2erta1.YourFtpClass.createFile(string filename1) <- I would expect this line!
e2erta.e2erta1..ctor()
```

Comment: Enable Debug information on "web.config" (<compilation debug="true">). So you can see exactly the line where the error occur.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that `filename1` starts with a `/` character. You can use the `Path.Combine` method to handle this case:

```
var path = Path.Combine("ftp://ftp.dunyameri.com/pt/", filename1);
var tmpReq1 = (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(path);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Url should be something like "ftp://" + userName + ":" + password + "@" + serverAddress + ":" + serverPort + "/" + file.

Try to add port.

Answer (score 0):

The class FtpWebRequest does not have a Create method seelink http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest_methods

The example shown on link casts WebRequest.Create to FtpWebRequest this might be the issue

Comment: cntsnwv0cn145.xx.xx.xxx.net-file.csv this is the value in this particular case ... I tried use ip 192.001.012.211-file.csv but it does not work. But when i use these file names on my system it does work fine.